# is it possible to copy a range from excel sheet to datagridview

Tags: c#, excel

is it possible to copy a range from excel (open in desktop) and paste to datagridview cells in one go rather than copying each cells separately. I am using C# form to customise civil3D wherein i would like to copy data from excel file open in desktop to datagrid and further process it.

Comment: `(object[,])Range.Value`??

Comment: One way you should do it, could be read in the excel file pragmatically and then copy the contents to the datagridview,